# persistently replicating RDS MySQL database to external slave

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-administration

AWS now allows you [to replicate data from an RDS instance to an external MySQL database](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html).

However, according to the docs:

> Replication to an instance of MySQL running external to Amazon RDS is only supported during the time it takes to export a database from a MySQL DB instance. The replication should be terminated when the data has been exported and applications can start accessing the external instance.

Is there a reason for this?  Can I choose to ignore this if I want the replication to be persistent and permanent?  Or does AWS enforce this somehow?  If so, are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like Amazon explicitly states why they don't support ongoing replication other than the statement you quoted.  In my experience, if AWS doesn't explicitly document a reason for why they do something then you're not likely to find out unless they decide to document it at a later time.

My guess would be that it has to do with the dynamic nature of Amazon instances and how they operate within RDS.  RDS instances can have their IP address change suddenly without warning. We've encountered that on more than one occasion with the RDS instances that we run.  According to the RDS [Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html) guide :

> If your client application is caching the DNS data of your DB instances, set a TTL of less than 30 seconds. Because the underlying IP address of a DB instance can change after a failover, caching the DNS data for an extended time can lead to connection failures if your application tries to connect to an IP address that no longer is in service.

Given that RDS instances can and do change their IP address from time to time my guess is that they simply want to avoid the possibility of having to support people who set up external replication only to have it suddenly break if/when an RDS instance gets assigned a new IP address.  Unless you set the replication user and any firewalls protecting your external mysql server to be pretty wide open then replication could suddenly stop if the RDS master reboots for any reason (maintenance, hardware failure, etc). From a security point of view, opening up your replication user and firewall port like that are not a good idea.

Comment: AWS discussed this topic in a webinar.  Essentially, yes, you can leave it on indefinitely -- as long as you know how to maintain it, since it's not part of the supported product offering.  There's a link to the webinar and more discussion in this answer on Database Administrators Stack Exchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34645/11651